# Javascript help, toggle text keeps jumping back to top of page

Tags: javascript, text, toggle

I hope someone can help with this issue, I've tried many scripts and workarounds, but can't get this simple thing to work. As the title has it, how can I make my text NOT jump to the top of the page. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleVisibility() {
  document.getElementById("toggleMe").style.display = "";
  if(document.getElementById("toggleMe").style.visibility == "hidden" ) {
    document.getElementById("toggleMe").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById("toggleMe").style.visibility = "hidden";
   ev.preventDefault();
    return false;

  }
}
</script>



 <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility();">Click to toggle visibility.</a></p>
 
<div id="toggleMe" style="visibility: hidden;"> Something to Hide and show.
```

Display collapses it's layout while visibility will keep it's layout.

All in the same html file. I read what outhers did and I tried the

ev.preventDefault();
return false;

code at the end of the function, but nothing.

Comment: you don't need ev.preventDefault(); return false; also depending on the rest of your markup there could be some nuances, for example missing closing tags, other improper html, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Change the `href` attribute in the `A` tag to: `javascript:;` instead of `#`

So use this to create your javascript enabled anchor:

```
<a href="javascript:;">
```

**added (background info):**

> The `#` character indicates a bookmark. By omitting the name of the bookmark e.g. `#bottom` the browser considers the bookmark as 'top of the page' thus scrolling to the top. Your problem does not have to do anything with bookmarks, however using `#` to define an *empty* link for a javascript enabling anchor (`A`) tags is not the way to go. You should use: `javascript:;` or `javascript:void(0);` to indicate that this is not a navigation anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply always return false, not just in the Else clause.